# How to programatically turn on .net 2.0. Is this correct?

Tags: .net, windows-8, installation

I'm trying to programatically turn on (install) the .Net 2.0 Framework  *Windows feature*. (B/c Windows 7 and above doesn't let you install .net manually and my customers are never going to be able to enable that from the control panel.). Windows 7 includes .net 2.0 but Windows 8 does not (at least in my testing)

I think the answer is:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3
```

based on many posts [including this one.](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Aug/27/NET-35-Installation-Problems-in-Windows-8)

1. Is the [most] correct way to install the .net 3.0 framework?
2. Is there any way to install *just* the .net **2.0** framework?

What I've tried;

- using the /get features of dism.exe to get all features it can turn on. The only .net listed was netfx3

Comment: Win7 does *not* include .NET 2.0, it has 3.5 pre-installed.  Win8 has 4.5 pre-installed, you can get 3.5 with dism but not 2.0.  The installer for 2.0 is no longer available.

Comment: @Hans, 3.5 includes 3.0 AND 2.0. The *standalone* 2.0 installer is still available, you just can't USE it on Win 7 (although it's not necessary) and Win 7.

Comment: Sure.  No, you can't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also trigger the [Windows Features on Demand User Experiance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj571719.aspx) applet directly without having to start a .Net executable or the setup.  This is supported only only Windows 8 ([per this chart](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/a/command-availability.htm))

```
fondue.exe /enable-feature:NetFx3
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: It is not your job as an ISV to manage installation of the .net framework, call the .Net Framework [installation bootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx#web_bootstrapper_packages) and be done with it.  System admins may wish to deploy the software  in different ways, make sure you are not limiting yourself by making assumptions.

The long answer: Use the [deployment guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbb4k3e.aspx) to determine how to package your application with the .net Framework.

---

Update regarding DISM:

I didn't mean to suggest that DISM is going to dissappear, only that references to DISM are being replaced with references to powershell and that DISM is a purely administrative tool.  For example, compare the MSDN documentation on [Installation of Windows Features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831809.aspx) for Windows Server 2012 which hilights [Install-WindowsFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205467.aspx) for administrative installation of features and only mentions DISM briefly to [the equivelent documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441253%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for 2008 R2.

However, I maintain that actions like adding and removing roles and features should not be performed silently as the result of an application installation. Per the [deployment guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbb4k3e.aspx), the reccomended installation method for chaining the .Net Framework is to call the bootstrapper and leave the rest to it.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160716.aspx) for exact arguments.

The bootstrapper, which would normally install the .net framework in a lower version of Windows, is shimmed and replaced by the dialog listed below - as long as there are no other deployment concerns (media, permissions, group policy, etc...)  The feature is installed and everyone is happy.  If there are deployment concerns, the user is directed to the Server Management tool, where it can be enabled manually.

[image: Turn Windows Features on or off]

Beyond the [formal guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbb4k3e.aspx) for installation of the .Net Framework, on demand installation is referenced as the preferred method for maintaning compatibility in the below documents:

- [New features in .Net 4.5 (Slide 8)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/4/0/640BF4BD-D92A-4592-958F-1BB90C8D07A4/TD11BE52.pptx) 
   "Preferred: Your setup tries to install 3.5 MSI ... shim installs correct version..."
- [Windows 8 and .Net Framework 3.5](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/05/14/windows-8-and-net-framework-3-5.aspx) 
   "You attempt to install .Net 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5 using a redistributable package available for download from Microsoft... an application shim in Windows 8 intercepts the attempt and invokes the installation of the new .Net 3.5 feature. Once triggered, the installation should proceed as if it was initiated from the UI, DISM, or Powershell."
- [Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) 
   "To run applications that require the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8, you must enable version 3.5 on your computer. There are two ways you can do this: by installing or running an application that requires the .NET Framework 3.5 (that is, by installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on demand), or by enabling the .NET Framework 3.5 in Control Panel."

Comment: Mitch,  That deployment guide is for 4.5, which does not get my app what it needs( .Net 2.). The only .net 2.0 installer I know of is the full .net 2.0 installer from Microsoft. And as I mentioned, When you run that installer Win 8 immediately prompts you to install .net via the Add Windows Features (Win 7 does something similar) . I'm just trying to get the O/S to that point Actually, using the dism.exe is handing over the installation process to the O/S even *moreso* then running an install bootstrapper.  *immediately* .

Comment: You can select a different version of the .net framework at the top of the page.  The .Net 2 version is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbb4k3e(v=vs.80).aspx.  I understand that dism using the OS installer, but DISM is formally part of the Windows Automated Installation Kit - a sys-admin tool and it appears to be being replaced by the Install-WindowsFeature powershell command.

Comment: Mitch, those instructions just take me back to downloading the DotNetFX installer or using the Active Directory or System Management Server (which both sound like they may have other dependencies, which I want to avoid).  And as I mentioned, when I run the .net 2.0 installer on Windows 8, it reports that it needs .net 2.0 and then offers to install it from the Add/Remove Windows Features (never actually running the .net installer).

Comment: Mitch, can you provide any references to DISM being discontinued? I can't find anything on that and the Microsoft page on DISM was updated this year and has no mention of that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371719(v=vs.85).aspx