# How can i configure the application manifest file to use a different dll in different OS

Tags: c#, .net

I have two versions of a same .net project dlls.One dll with .net 2.0 and one with .net 4.0 versions.This dll is referenced inside a .net demo project.When i run the exe generated by the Demo project in a  Win7 OS or lower OS then exe should use  .net 2.0 based dll.When i run the application in Windows 8 then it should use .net 4.0 based dll.How can i configure this using an application manifest file.IS there any other simpler methods.

Thanks,

Comment: What about on Win7 with .Net4 installed?

Comment: Actually Win7 have .net 3.5 and Win8 have a .net 4.5 frameworks installed by  default. .net 3.5 is under .net CLR 2.0.So any versions of .net ie .net2.0,3.0,3.5 will work with .net clr 2.0.But  .net 4.5 is using  CLR 4.0.We didn't want our users to install the .net framework manually.

Comment: I'm aware of that and understand it - I often target 2.0 for compatibility reasons... But that doesn't mean someone hasn't installed it already - eg if I were to use your product with the latest 4.5 installed, I'd like the extra features that  the 4.0 brings... If there are no extra features, why not just use the 2.0 version across all platforms? How about having a noddy 2.0 launcher that executes the appropriate version of the app?

Comment: My aplication is crashing when i use dll under 2.0 in Windows 8

Comment: Sounds like you're hitting this problem... http://www.sliqtools.co.uk/blog/technical/problems-running-net-2-0-programs-on-windows-8/ This is an annoyance but a proper installer with the .Net bootstrapper should handle this for you - see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13498091/156755